# Why can't define string array using char **?

Tags: c

We can assign a string constant to `char *` or `char [ ]` just like:

```
char *p = "hello";
char a[] = "hello";
```

Now for string **array**, naturally it'll be like this:

```
char **p = {"hello", "world"};   //  Error
char *a[] = {"hello", "world"};
```

the first way will generate a warning when compiling, and has a `Segmentation fault` when I'm trying to print the string constant with `printf("%s\n", p[0]);`

Why ?

Comment: "generate a warning", and that warning is ...?

Comment: @chux , "initialization from incompatible pointer type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char **p = {"hello", "world"};
```

Here, `p` is a pointer to pointer to `char` which can't be initialized with an an array initializer with an array of pointers (each of the string literals gets converted into a pointer during initialization -- actual type of a string literal in C is `char[n]`).

The *types* are incompatible i.e. p is of type `char **` and RHS is of type `char *[]`. Hence, the diagnostic is issued by the compiler.

Whereas,

`char *a[] = {"hello", "world"};`

is valid as `a` is an array of pointers to `char` and the types match. Hence this is a valid initialization.

---

Since C99, the C language supports *Compound literals (6.5.2.5, C99)* using which you can initialize:

```
char **p = (char *[]) {"hello", "world"};
```

So either use compound literals if C99 or later is supported by your compiler. Otherwise, stick to the array of pointers initialization (`char *a[]`).

You can read about various examples on [compound literals here (gcc manual).](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

Answer (score 1):

because `char **p` is a pointer to pointer not an array of pointers, where `char* a[]` is an array of pointers

```
char *ptr ="hello";
```

defines `ptr` to be a pointer to the (read-only) string `"hello"`, and thus contains the address of string say `100`. `ptr` must itself be stored somewhere: say location `200.`

```
char **p = &ptr;
```

Now `p` points to `ptr`, that is, it contains the address of `ptr` (which is 200).

```
printf("%s",**p);
```

So your creating a `pointer to another pointer` but not extra memory to store more than one string but `char *a[]` creates array of pointers depends on the size you have given

**an advice**

Do not use `char *p = "hello";`
use `const char *p = "hello";`
because string literals are saved in read only memory

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, because char **p points to a pointer, not to an array of pointers.

That happens because you need to build the array your self. For each level (or dimension) you need to reserve memory for the pointer holders.

What you need to do is:

```
// this holds you pointers
char **p = malloc( sizeof( char *) * nr of elements);

// to set the elements, you need to:
p[0] = "hello";
p[1] = "world";
```

And this needs to be done for as many levels (or dimensions) you have.

Answer (score 0):

First, `char *p = "hello"` is different from `char a[] = "hello"`.

```
char *p = "hello"
```

`"hello"` is actually a pointer to literal constant. You assign a pointer to literal constant to `p`. So It's better to use `const char *p = "hello"`.

```
char a[] = "hello"
```

The characters in `"hello"` were copied to array `a` with a `'\0'` end.

Second,

```
char *a[]
```

defines a array of pointers, so it's OK to use `char *a[] = {"hello", "world"};`

```
char **p
```

defines a pointer to a pointer to a char, so it makes no sense to using `char **p = {"hello", "world"};`